# Installer for web application

Tags: java, web-applications

We have developed a web application which is to be deployed by nontechnical person. Therefor I want to create an installer for it. Installer has functions of installing JVM, Apache Tomcat, and the web application war file depending on whether they are installed or not. Is there any installation suit which I can use to achieve this?

Comment: What are the platform specs? But, you may use NSIS: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page

Comment: Do you also need to setup a database?

Comment: @Thilo: Database is remote so no need for that

Comment: When you say "non-technical person," do you simply mean your sys admins/support staff simply don't know how to do this? Or are end users expected to install this on their workstations?

Comment: @Jack Leow:Its an intranet application so it can be anyone admin or end user, @baris_a: thanks nsis is good http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Embedding_other_installers

Comment: @baris_a: Post it as an answer, this helped me a lot http://nsis.sourceforge.net/A_script_to_install_a_Tomcat_web_application

Answer (score 2):

If you're aiming for a linux platform the best way to do this would be to create packages (rpm or deb) with dependencies for the jvm and tomcat.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mentioned platform is windows

Answer (score 1):

The [Winstone Project](http://winstone.sourceforge.net/#embedding) supports executable WAR files (with the Servlet Container and your web application embedded in the executable jar), which takes you half-way (still need to install Java).

> To use this, simply unpack the winstone JAR, and place your WAR file inside the unpacked folder at the top level (with the same parent as the folder named "winstone"). Then rename your WAR file to "embedded.war", and repack the jar as before (make sure to preserve the META-INF and manifest).
>
> Now if you type: "java -jar winstone.jar", your application should automatically deploy as the ROOT web application. Try http://localhost:8080/ to check it out.
>
> If you need to add any default command-line arguments (eg ports or prefixes), you can embed a properties file in exactly the same way, except that the file must be named "embedded.properties".

Maybe this can be combined with one of the tools that creates installers out of jar files.

Comment: I have had good experiences with wrapping a single JAR file with JSMooth as it gives an EXE file which downloads the required JRE if not present.